# Tkinter - How to immediately create widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a chess AI, and have written my own Tkinter code for the board. When the user makes a move, the board does not change until the computer is finished with its turn, which sometimes takes a long time. I'm pretty sure this is because the images are only created when the `window.mainloop()` line comes up, which is after the computer's turn. Is there a way to immediately change the board? Below is a shortened version of the code for changing the board. `piece.lbl` is the Tkinter label which is the image for a certain piece, and `piece.position` is the position of the piece.

```
def create_images(board, Labels):
    for square in chess.SquareSet(chess.BB_ALL):
        if bool(board.piece_at(square)):
            piece = board.piece_at(square)
            Labels.append(piece.lbl)
            piece.lbl.grid(row = (0 - (piece.position // 8) + 7), column = piece.position % 8 + 1)
            piece.lbl.bind('<Button-1>', partial(user_click, turn, piece.position))
```

The functions run in the following order:

```
user_turn()
create_images()
computer_turn()
create_images()
window.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to create the images before reaching the last line? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `window.update_idletasks()` or `window.update()`; that sometimes works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Just one issue, though: the screen flashes black for a fraction of a second every time `window.update()` is called, is there any way to avoid this? (`window.update_idletasks` didn't work for me)